# Stop 2sxc pop-ups and rollovers

Tags: 2sxc

We have 2sxc installed on DNN Evoq Content 9.3.0. The every time I view a page in edit mode the "Auto-Configure Designed Content" page pops up. I have installed the recommended content package but the pop up will not go away. In addition, as you mouse over the page the add content and add app icons pop-up and prevent me from navigating to the page I want. How can I get this module to stop taking over the pages I am just trying to view and edit?

I have installed the recommended content package

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow :)

If the auto-configure pops up, you have added a content-module on the page and haven't installed the content-package (at least not on this portal). So either do install it, or remove the empty module.

If quickE (quick edit) is causing trouble, you can disable it both at the theme, pane or module level. You can find out more about this here:

1. [using quickE](https://azing.org/2sxc/r/vdLJ0Etz)
2. [quickE concept](https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/concept-quick-edit)
3. [configuring quickE](https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/Html-Js-%24quickE)